# Reservation: I want to display all records with a condition including if the record is null in table number 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing a reservation system where I will display all the records to the user where the status is Verified, the carType is the same as the user wants, and records with the same service type as user input. The problem is, the record does not show if the car record does not have an existing record in the booking table. The checker for overlapping dates work but it does not show other records that is verified, same service type, same cartype but null at booking table.

```
    $startDate = '2019-06-04 07:00:00';
    $endDate = '2019-06-20 07:00:00';
    $serviceType = "Self-drive";
    $carType = "SUV";


    $sql = "SELECT carrecord.recordID, carrecord.recordLong, carrecord.recordLat, 
model.brandName, model.modelName, carrecord.amount, model.carType, carrecord.status, 
carrecord.recordPicture, booking.recordID AS bookRecordID FROM carrecord
    LEFT JOIN booking
    ON booking.recordID = carrecord.recordID
    LEFT JOIN car
    ON car.carID  =  carrecord.carID
    LEFT JOIN model
    ON model.modelID = car.modelID  
    WHERE
    model.carType = '$carType'
    AND
    carrecord.serviceType = '$serviceType'
    AND
    carrecord.status = 'Verified'
    OR booking.recordID IS NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT booking.recordID FROM booking 
        WHERE '$startDate' <= booking.endDate
        AND '$endDate' >= booking.startDate
        AND booking.status = 'Accepted'
    )";
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question well yet but if you want to see all `car` regardless if it has `carrecord` or not, aren't you suppose to put the `car` table first at the `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Hello thanks commenting on my post, but the results are the same whether the car table is the first left join or not.

Comment: I see, then it might be the `WHERE` condition. Can we have example data of the table corresponding with the query? thanks

Answer (score 1):

change you where `booking.recordID IS NULL`,model.carType = '$carType' condition and move those in on clause

```
SELECT carrecord.recordID, carrecord.recordLong, carrecord.recordLat, 
model.brandName, model.modelName, carrecord.amount, model.carType, carrecord.status, 
carrecord.recordPicture, booking.recordID AS bookRecordID
    FROM carrecord
    LEFT JOIN booking
    ON booking.recordID = carrecord.recordID           
    LEFT JOIN car
    ON car.carID  =  carrecord.carID
    LEFT JOIN model
    ON model.modelID = car.modelID  and model.carType = '$carType'
    WHERE   carrecord.serviceType = '$serviceType'
    AND
   carrecord.status = 'Verified'     

     NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT booking.recordID FROM booking 
        WHERE '$startDate' <= booking.endDate
        AND '$endDate' >= booking.startDate
        AND booking.status = 'Accepted'
    )
```

Comment: It's still not displaying the records that are NULL from the booking table.

Comment: @CarlJames if booking.recordID is in that case no  mapping is available then how it will show booking tables data ???

Comment: thanks for the insight, it made me think of the solution. Already solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `booking.recordID NOT IN ( ... )` rather than `NOT EXISTS` ?

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is what people usually want. (Different null value behavior.)

Comment: It shows me a mysqli error. I think I am in the right track of using NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by putting both possibilities to a ()
The code is

```
$sql = "SELECT carrecord.recordID, carrecord.recordLong, carrecord.recordLat, model.brandName, model.modelName, 
carrecord.amount, model.carType, carrecord.status, carrecord.recordPicture, booking.recordID AS bookRecordID FROM carrecord
LEFT JOIN booking
ON booking.recordID = carrecord.recordID 
LEFT JOIN car
ON car.carID = carrecord.carID
LEFT JOIN model
ON model.modelID = car.modelID 
WHERE
(model.carType = '$carType'
AND
carrecord.serviceType = '$serviceType'
AND
carrecord.status = 'Verified'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT booking.recordID FROM booking 
    WHERE '$startDate' <= booking.endDate
    AND '$endDate' >= booking.startDate
    AND booking.status = 'Accepted'
)) 
OR (booking.recordID IS NULL
AND 
model.carType = '$carType' 
AND
carrecord.status = 'Verified'
AND
carrecord.serviceType = '$serviceType')";
```